# Better way to convert a list of Years expressed by a int datatype to DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have the following list of integers containing Years and I want to convert to DatetimeIndex.

```
date_1=[2000,2001,2002,2003]
#converting to string
date_1_str=[str(i) for i in date_1]
#converting to Datetime
test=pd.to_datetime(date_1_str,format="%Y")
print(test)
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2002-01-01', '2003-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Why I can't do something more direct like:

```
pd.to_datetime(date_1, unit="Y")
```

Why I have to convert first to a string datatype?

There is any better option available?

Comment: don't let the *datatype* fool you - only because it's `int`, it's still a year in a certain *format* (see jezrael's answer). Given those are 64bit integers, 4 bytes of ASCII would even be more efficient! I'd stick with the conversion to string and then parsing that.

Comment: Yes I was completely fooled, I have good reason to feel dumb! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think reason is `unit` parameter in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) working different, working with unix times:

> **unit** , default ‘ns’

> The unit of the arg (D,s,ms,us,ns) denote the unit, which is an integer or float number. This will be based off the origin. Example, with unit=’ms’ and origin=’unix’ (the default), this would calculate the number of milliseconds to the unix epoch start.

But if values are years in  integers it is only different `format` of datetime, so for me this is more logic using here.

Comment: in addition, if I get the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) right, only units from `(D,s,ms,us,ns)` are allowed - which is reasonable because any time span greater than a week is ambiguous (e.g. month can have different number of days)

Comment: Yes, I was completely fooled guys thank you for your time :)